# How to skip authentication in .htaccess if the user comes from a specific web page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, https, server, subdomain

So I have multiple (sub)-domains. All of them link towards one server, but on different folders with different file structures. For example:

```
http://webapp1.example.com/  //Subdomains don't have https (no wildcard)
https://www.example.com/webapp_that_needs_https (some webapps are required to have https and therefore can't be on a subdomain)
http://webapp2.example.com/
```

Every webapp has its own .htpasswd-protection, this is the .htaccess-file:

```
# Password
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /www/serverid/webpages/webapp1/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Now I want to make a webpage on a subdomain, that lists and links all of the webapps. This file should be password-protected as well.
If the user navigates to one of the webapp-pages using this password-protected list, the htaccess-protection for the webapps should be skipped.

If the user skips the listing page and navigates directly to the webapp-domain, the password protection should appear as usual.

Is there any way to achieve this probably really uncommon feature?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using an `if directive`. In your `.htaccess` you would use:

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'example.com'">
    ....
</if>
```

So you would put the domain you want them to refer from in the `if directive` and if it does not match, then it runs the `Auth Type`. Leaving your final code with:

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'example.com'">
    # Password
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Password Protected Area"
    AuthUserFile /www/serverid/webpages/webapp1/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</if>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late answer! Using the <if> </if>, I had no success requesting the previous HTTP_HOST. I hope I'll find the time to dig deeper into it.